# Redux Keep showing undefine state

Tags: reactjs, redux, components, containers, state

I am new in React and Redux.
Though I find a lot source on the Internet but it still not working.
Hope someone can help me.

I want to use click to trigger a component
Q1 : I track initial state and find it works fine but it shows undefined in component 
Q2 : how can I keep subscribing the state? (like print it out with console.log)

---

Code: index.js

```
import .....

const store = createStore(rootReducer)
console.log(store.getState())
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
<App />
</Provider>,
document.getElementById('root')
)
```

---

App.js

```
import ToggleSidebar from '../containers/ToogleSidebar'
const App = () => (
<div>
     <ToggleSidebar/>
</div>
)
export default App
```

---

Reduce.js

```
const sidebar = (state={open:false}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'TOGGLE_SIDEBAR':
      return {
          ...state,
          open : !state.open
      }
      default:
      return state
    }
  }

  export default sidebar
```

Combined

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

import sidebar from './sidebar'
export default combineReducers({
  sidebar
})
```

Acion

```
export const toggleSideBar = () => ({
  type: 'TOGGLE_SIDEBAR',

})
```

---

Container

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { toggleSideBar } from '../actions'
import Sidebar from '../components/Sidebar'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
   open: '...'+state.open+'...'
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    toggleSideBar: () => dispatch(toggleSideBar())
})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Sidebar)
```

---

Component

```
const  Sidebar = ({open,toggleSideBar}) =>  (

        <div>
          <button onClick={toggleSideBar}>
            {open} 
          </button>
        </div>
)
  export default Sidebar
```

---

when I use log in the index.js I saw the inital state of "open"
but the button in component shows undefine
Please help me , thanks a lot

Comment: is ToggleSidebar the same component that is exported in containers after connecting sidebar to reducer

Comment: <ToggleSidebar/> is the container , I feel so confused when i named them , but people seems don't need to use more specific name ... so i guess I should try ... now I think I should name it like SidebarContainer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mapStateToProps` function in Container should be using `state.sidebar.open` instead of `state.open`. When you call `combineReducers({ sidebar })` you are creating a state structure like `{ sidebar: { open: false } }`. See the documentation on [combineReducers here](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers).

Comment: Thanks a lot to help me figure out ! 
May I also know how to keep subscribe the store ? 
I know how to do it without Provider in the index.js 
Should I just make App.js into a state Component so it will call it in componentwillmount ? please give me some advice

Comment: You're welcome! I'm sorry, but I don't follow what you are asking. The `connect` function subscribes to the store for you. Any time the state is updated, any connected (container) components will retrieve the new values from the state using `mapStateToProps`. You shouldn't need to do any manual subscribing in `componentWillMount` or anywhere else. If this doesn't answer your question, I would suggest posting another StackOverflow question and providing some code examples to show the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I just want to print it out just like store does, but now I think what I should do is print the state directly, thanks for clarify my confuse! :)